# Swift compiler error in AWS. Using swift 3.0 "could not build awsCore"

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, swift3

I am having a problem with my migration to 3.0 and I am not sure how to attack it. I updated my pods as follow:

```
post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I was able to point to 3.0 versions of OauthSiwft and Swiftcharts, however AWS has no branches or anything like that so I am pointing to their newest as follow:

```
pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSCognitoIdentityProvider'
pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
pod 'AWSEC2'
pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
pod 'AWSIoT' 
pod 'AWSKinesis'
pod 'AWSLambda'
pod 'AWSMachineLearning'
pod 'AWSMobileAnalytics'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
pod 'AWSSNS'
pod 'AWSSQS'
```

from my understanding AWS migrated to 3.0 however when I "build" I get the following error:

[image: Error:]

The warning in the top is already set to No but I still get the error.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: clear derived data folder and run again. it in Go to File -> Workspace setting  @Tonatiuh Mendoza

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I did what you just recommended and it did not work. I get the same errors.

Comment: Again refer this if any updates are there, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html. Also try to add pod for AWSCore. @Tonatiuh Mendoza

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. It was the cocoapods that was not the most current version. I was using Brew but it was throwing an error saying "the library is installed but not linked" Once I fixed that issue it worked.

I appreciate the help!